# Get single MGLPolylineFeature of MGLMultiPolylineFeature on tap in MGLMapView

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I would like to detect a tap on my map and identify the polyline, I tapped on. As there are a LOT of polylines, I but them into a MGLMultiPolylineFeature (as this seems to perform much much better)

I create that like so:

```
let polyline = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
polyline.attributes = [
  "identifier": "my-polyline-identifier",
]
    
let multiPolylineFeature = MGLMultiPolylineFeature(polylines: polylines)
multiPolylineFeature.attributes = [
  "identifier": "my-multipolyline-identifier",
]
```

Now when tapping on the map, I find the features like so:

```
let fingerRect = CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 0, height: 0).insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -10)
let features = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: fingerRect)
```

Those contain my `MGLMultiPolylineFeature` and I also find the `.polylines`. But non of them are  `MGLPolylineFeature` but rather `MGLPolyline`, so without `.attributes`. Also setting a title on the original polyline, it's not there any more.

So my question is: is there any way to identify a polyline of a MGLMultiPolylineFeature?